# Bash - extract some strings from a file using regex

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have the file below:

```
some lines = \
   some params

SUBDIRS = \
    text1 \
    text2 \
#  commented text
   text3 \
       text4 \

OTHERS = \
     other text here \
```

I want to extract a list containing `text1`, `text2`, `text3`, `text4`.
How can I proceed?

Comment: The question is a bit incomplete. You've not specified how you want to identify the file names to be extracted. Pulling them by name is not very hard: `grep -ow 'text[0-9]'` could do the job for the example (assuming GNU `grep`). If you want the file list associated with `SUBDIRS`, then you have to work harder — this is what the answers so far have assumed.  What should the output format be? One word per line without backslashes?  Does the code need to handle all the niceties of `make` syntax?  How will you invoke the command?  What should happen if the name specified is not found in the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. SPACE_TAB is, I hope obviously, a space plus a tab.

```
$ SPACE_TAB="   "; sed -ne '/^SUBDIRS/,/^['"$SPACE_TAB"']*$/p' test.in
SUBDIRS = \
    text1 \
    text2 \
#  commented text
   text3 \
       text4 \
```

Comment: Since this question is tagged `bash`, you may want to use `SPACE_TAB=$'\t '` in order to be sure that the correct characters are assigned to the variable.

Comment: I don't even want there to be a variable! I just put that in there to call it out.

Comment: In that case, you can use the POSIX form for space-tab: `sed -ne '/^SUBDIRS/,/^[[:blank:]]*$/p'`

Answer (score 1):

This extracts all the lines after SUBDIRS but before OTHERS excluding lines that start with `#` or are empty:

```
$ awk '/OTHERS/{f=0} f && /./ && !/^#/{print} /SUBDIRS/{f=1}' file
    text1 \
    text2 \
   text3 \
       text4 \
```

#### How it works

This program uses one variable, `f`: f is 1 when we are in the desired range of lines and 0 elsewhere.

- `/OTHERS/{f=0}`

  If we have reached `OTHERS`, then set `f` back to zero.
- `f && /./ && !/^#/{print}`

  If `f` is nonzero (`f`) *and* the line is not blank (`/./`) *and* the line does not start with `#` (`!/^#/`), then print this line.
- `/SUBDIRS/{f=1}`

  If we have reached the line containing `SUBDIRS`, then set `f` to 1.

#### Slightly briefer form

Because `print` is the default action when no action is specified, we can omit it from the script:

```
$ awk '/OTHERS/{f=0} f && /./ && !/^#/; /SUBDIRS/{f=1}' file
    text1 \
    text2 \
   text3 \
       text4 \
```

#### Alternative output format

This removes the trailing `\` and combines all the output to one line:

```
$ awk '/OTHERS/{f=0} $NF=="\\"{$NF=""} f && /./ && !/^#/{a=a" "$0} /SUBDIRS/{f=1} END{print a}' file
 text1  text2  text3  text4
```